# How to export VRML including texture from 3D Studio Max

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, vrml

I am using 3D Studio Max 2011. I manage to export VRML by `File / Export / …VRML` but all the texture information gets lost by this. How do you export a model as VRML including its texture?

Answer (score 1):

Are there no `texCoord` or `texCoordIndex` in the `IndexedFaceSet` nodes ?

Several things you can try:

- convert primitives like Box to Meshes
- use only jpeg images
- add an UVUnwrap to all meshes
- make sure UV coordinates are in channel 1
- use only Standard materials

Answer (score 0):

save the textures in one folder then when export put the folder location in bitmap URL prefix